# Store comments on networking site with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a MySQL database for a project in which users can come and make comments on other profile. Every profile has a unique id to identify it, now when a user comes and makes comment on other profile I'll need to store the user id of the person who made the comment and the person on whose profile the comment was made, along with that I'll need to store the comment in the database.

As many users can make comments on a single profile, I'll need to store all the comments and the users who made them on a single profile. For this how many tables should I create and how many columns should they have? For this I'm thinking about creating a table for named user_comments and that has column `user_id`, `commenter_id` (all the commenter who commented their id separated by comma), comments (then all the user comments separated by comma).

Will this work?

Comment: You are on the right track, why don't you try to think of a good table structure and ask us what we think of it?

Comment: Exactly *one* table "`comments`" with a necessary number of 3 columns, maybe two or three more depending on what kind of meta data you want to store.

Comment: Please check it now ,I made update with what I'm thinking about .

Comment: Don't be tempted to add fields containing CSV data - it is nearly guaranteed to turn into a mess. You can do it for very limited uses (Wordpress options uses it to good effect) but usually you should store this in relational form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For this I'm thinking about creating a table for named user_comments
>   and that has column user_id ,commenter_id(all the commenter who
>   commented their id seprated by comma) ,comments(then All the user
>   comments seprated by comma)

God **no**! You are *almost* there:

```
Table comments
id           INT AUTO_INCREMENT
recipient_id
sender_id
message      TEXT
[ sent       DATETIME ]
[ other meta data ]
```

Store *one* message in `message`. Create *one row* per message. Never store several records in the same field separated by anything.

Comment: Ok ,so there are going to be several rows with the same recipient_id and sender_id and message will be different .t

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a `profile_comment` table:

```
id, text, profile_user_id, commenter_user_id, created_at
```

And a `user` table:

```
id, name, email
```

You can see here that the first table has two foreign keys to the user table - one points to the owner of the profile, and the other points to the owner of the comment. You can sort them in order of `created_at` to list them as you would on a blog, either in forward or reverse order.

Now, when you are rendering a profile page, you can get the profile `id` from your query string:

```
$profileId = isset( $_GET['profile_id'] ) ? $_GET['profile_id'] : null;
```

From there, you can add it into a SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM profile_comment
WHERE profile_user_id = :profile_id
ORDER BY created_at
```

The colon mark here is a placeholder you can use with a *parameterised* query, which helps protect against SQL injection. However, you *can* build the statement as a string if you are careful to untaint any user input you insert into it.

Comment: `profile_user_id` is the key of the profile a user is commenting on. If you didn't record that, then you could only see which users have commented (via `commenter_user_id`) but you'd have no record of _where_ they have commented.